# JS Timezone not changing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run the following code however I cannot get the correct output.
This script is supposed to be able to change the date and timezone based up the parameters set, however when outputted the time will show correctly for the timezone but the timezone name will always display my local timezone despite it being referenced to use the timezone that has been set in the first time.
[The timezone is set for EST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gEBx.png)
As you see with the code the timezone is set to EST however the "t" which displays the text version of the timezone is displaying the local timezone and now using the one specified on line one.

```
function init() {
  est = new Date().toLocaleString("en-us", { timeZone: "America/New_York" }); // sets timezone to EST
  d = new Date(est); // Declares a new date object
  h = d.getHours();
  m = d.getMinutes();
  s = d.getSeconds();
  t = d.toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZoneName: 'short' }).split(' ').pop();
  clock();
  day = d.getDate();
  month = d.getMonth();
  year = d.getFullYear();
};
```

Comment: Please remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and use [proper markup](/markdown). You are expected to put some effort into writing a decent post so that people can easily read it, and understand what you're asking, with code shown as code.

Comment: Dates in javascript don't store a timezone, they are stored as timestamps so when you print `t` to localeString and don't specify a timezone it just uses the system timezone.

Comment: When attempting to specify a timezone for `t` it changes the output to display just "PM" and not "EST" based upon the example. This happens for any timezone that is specified

Comment: That's because `en-us` format does not have a timezone component, but also doesn't use a 24hr clock, so it displays the time as it is in the specified time zone (America/New York) but within the constraints of the specified locale format. Perhaps you want [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) which allows you to specify which date/time elements get printed.